# How to hide content for logged out users?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a section at the bottom of my page with icons that navigates members (logged-in) from different pages. It consists of 'profile', 'leads', 'orders' and 'filter'.

I wish for non-logged-in users (customers) not to see this navigation section as the the customers can check a members profile and do not want them entering those pages.

Is there a way to hide this section to non-logged in users?

The section's class I want to hide is called 'icon-container'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://is_user_logged_in()) to check if whether the current visitor is a logged in user.

So, in the php file, you can do it like this:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>

  <section>
  </section>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thus, the `<section>` will only be rendered if the user is logged in.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for getting back to me. Do you know if there is a way to add this to the section inside my wordpress editor using elementor. Im struggling to find a way to a php to this. Thankyou

Comment: I think it is not possible In Elementor. Instead of using Elementor, consider doing this in a php file. Maybe in the Footer file. I don't know if you are a developer, but it is not that hard. It is a matter of researching and doing one thing at a time.

Comment: Okay i will try to do that now and let you know how i get on